# How to keep the session alive while subscribing push topic using lightning empApi?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, streaming-api, empapi

I have a requirement to subscribe to push topic for which i have implemented using lightning empApi and have open the browser in a VM for continuous reading of events and do some actions. The issue is with session settings and i am getting logged out after session timeout stating - You've been logged out due to inactivity.

Is there a way to keep listening to the push topic and avoid this message?

Comment: It is likely you are logged out because of your session settings. You can either increase that to 24 hours or send at least one request to Salesforce before the session timeout. It can be a page reload, a request to salesforce or a small pixel vf page reloading after 90 minutes or so.

Comment: Yes i'm getting logged out as the session setting is set to 2hrs but even though i set the expiration to 24hrs i will have to manually go and do some activity before the session expires. I also tried to keep the session alive using polling but i stopped receiving the pushtopic events after 60-70 mins. So i am looking for way to implement streaming client within Salesforce that has this capability to keep running in the backend.